# Given a smooth function $u$, what is the meaning of $\nabla u \otimes D^2 u$ (where $D^2$ is the Hessian matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, tensor-products

Given a smooth function $u$, how does one compute $\nabla u \otimes D^2 u$ (where $D^2$ is the Hessian matrix and $\otimes$ is the tensor product) and what is its meaning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use index notation (and in the process assume Cartesian coordinates) to elucidate.

In index form, those objects look like:

$$\nabla u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}, \quad D^2 u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}$$

Taking the tensor product of both of them just means tacking everything together:

$$\nabla u \otimes D^2 u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}$$

This is a third-order tensor as noted by the three different indices. If you're trying to get some insight into what this object might represent, consider the following representation:

$$\nabla u \otimes D^2 u = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}\right)$$

In coordinate-free notation, this would appear to indicate:

$$\nabla u \otimes D^2 u = \frac{1}{2}\nabla\left(\nabla u\otimes \nabla u\right)$$

Hope this is helpful! Feel free to call me out if the third expression is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I have an additional question: $\nabla u = (\partial_{x_1} u, \dots, \partial_{x_n} u) $ is a vector, $D^2 u = \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} \partial^2_{x_1} u & \dots  &
 \partial_{x_1}\partial_{x_n} u \\ \dots & \dots & \dots\\ \partial_{x_1}\partial_{x_n}  u & \dots  &
 \partial^2_{x_n}u \end{array} } \right)$ is a matrix. What does the tensor product of the two look like?

Comment: A third-rank tensor (which is what the tensor product of those two things is) can be in some heuristic sense interpreted as a "3-D matrix"; that is, it's a "matrix" with not just columns and rows, but also "lanes" pointing inwards or outwards of the page/screen you're seeing them in. This is a very unrefined/restrictive interpretation of it, but hopefully it's instructive to build some intuition on tensors!

Comment: I see. Thanks. And what does it mean to say $\nabla u \otimes D^2 u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for example?

Comment: I -suspect- it means that every component of that third-order tensor is square integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is presumably the original domain of $u$ as well.